# SRSS if / else SWITCH

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I have a bar graph which I would like to have different colours for each category.

So far I'm doing it with a SWITCH but I couldn't see how / if it's possible to put an else on the end there.

My code looks like this:

```
    =SWITCH(
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Vagabond Pale Ale", "CornflowerBlue",
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "This Is Lager", "Orange", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Punk IPA", "#00AFDB", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Nanny State", "White", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Jet Black Heart", "DimGray", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Dead Pony Club", "SeaGreen", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "5am Red Ale", "Maroon", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "KingPin", "Orange", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Jack Hammer", "LimeGreen",  
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Libertine Black Ale","#7e000000", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Hardcore IPA","MidnightBlue", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Cocoa Psycho", "Indigo", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Elvis Juice", "Red")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in the end
    **True, "Yourcolor"**

```
  =SWITCH(
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Vagabond Pale Ale", "CornflowerBlue",
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "This Is Lager", "Orange", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Punk IPA", "#00AFDB", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Nanny State", "White", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Jet Black Heart", "DimGray", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Dead Pony Club", "SeaGreen", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "5am Red Ale", "Maroon", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "KingPin", "Orange", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Jack Hammer", "LimeGreen",  
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Libertine Black Ale","#7e000000", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Hardcore IPA","MidnightBlue", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Cocoa Psycho", "Indigo", 
Fields!Style_Name.Value = "Elvis Juice", "Red",
**True, "Black"**
)
```